# proof that $ log(p(x)) = ELBO(p,q,x) + KL(q(z)\parallel p(z\setminus x))$

Tags: statistics, optimization

How can I show that:
$$ \log(p(x)) = \operatorname E_{z\sim q}[\log(p(x\setminus z))] - \operatorname{KL}(q(z)\parallel p(z)) + \operatorname{KL}(q(z)\parallel p(z\setminus x)) $$

I will be happy if you can give an explanation in addition to the mathematical proof.

Comment: Have you tried just writing out the definition of KL-divergence?

Comment: I provide some explanation of how the ELBO is used in the EM algorithm in my answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2664303/151735

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, $$\operatorname{KL}(Q \parallel P) := E_{Z \sim Q} \left[\log \frac{Q(Z)}{P(Z)}\right].$$

So,
\begin{align}
\operatorname{KL}(q(z) \parallel p(z))
&= E_{z \sim q} \log \frac{q(z)}{p(z)}
\\
\operatorname{KL}(q(z) \parallel p(z \mid x))
&= \operatorname E_{z \sim q} \log \frac{q(z)}{p(z \mid x)}
\end{align}

Combine the three expectations on the right-hand side and note that $p(x \mid z) p(z) = p(z \mid x) p(x)$.